# “This app can't open” message when logged in as domain admin Windows 8

Tags: windows-8-preview

I have Windows 8 installed, joined the computer to our domain and logged in as the domain administrator.

Any time I try to open an app from the Metro UI I get the following message:

> This app can't open
>   [App name] Can't be opened using the Built-in Administrator account.
>   Sign in with a different account and try again.

If I try to run IE from the Metro menu I get that message but if I switch to desktop mode, I'm able to open IE.

Very strange, not sure if this is expected behavior or a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I agree Tom.  Since the beginning of operating systems, there has ALWAYS been a root or admin account that could do EVERYTHING.

From what I have read, it seems that this was added to the OS for auditing, data leakage, retention and compliance.  In other words, they have killed the built in admin accounts (local and domain admin) ability to run apps because apps can access data using "split tokens."  The user access control is turned on for these accounts so that they are limited in what they can reach, especially data, and everywhere they go, they leave a trail.

It looks like the idea is that you have the built in domain admin account and then a separate user account that is part of the domain admin organizational unit.

It flies in the face of all previous design, but the mar

Answer (score 1):

The admin account is locked for admin control in windows 8. So, those functions which are normally within the remit of an admin are still available, but those functions which are in the remit of a lessor user are locked out. At the moment metro functions are lessor user so locked out from admin use. I haven't found the logical way to apportion functions to user type yet (I'm sure its there somewhere though?).

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it.  The domain admin or computer admin should be able to run whatever they want.